# Do Maxwell equeations change somehow after Higg's boson finding?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, higgs, maxwell-equations

When I was in some physics -lesson, probably something to do with Quantum Physics -- the teacher said that certain Maxwell equations would change if the Higg's boson is found. It is also possible that I have mixed something, he may have meant magnetic monotones. Anyway does there exist any change to Maxwell equations after the Higg's boson?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing will change with Maxwell's equations due to the discovery of the Higgs bosons. Maxwell's equations describe the continuum of electromagnetic theory and know nothing about particle physics.

Comment: Simple and direct, I like it :-)